# Freeway/City Drive, City Run. Is there anyway to create this scenario when testing on a physical device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I understand how to simulate a city run, freeway drive when testing on a simulator. I just wondered if it's possible to do so on an actual device. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can, but not without **modifying your ios version**... You could try **jailbreaking** (with [checkra1n](https://checkra.in/) for exemple) and then installing a tool from cydia like [a gps spoofer](https://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=gpsmasterDp). It seem like jailbreaking is the only solution to achieve what you're trying to do.

**WARNING** : I'm not responsible in either way of damage that could create jailbreaking and modifying your ios version on your device

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I guess I might as well just get a super long cable and go for a run. :)